# How can I filter multiple variables and one of them is a Date in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Realm version -> 2.10

Swift version > 3

```
var uuid: String
var resolutionID: Int
var dateFrom: Date

...
```

I checked that the variables are not null.
I tried:

```
realm.objects(DeviceDataRealm.self).filter("device.uuid == '\(uuid)' AND resolution.idResolution == \(resolutionID) AND time > \(dateFrom)")
```

It does not work...

I tried with `NSPredicate` too:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "device.uuid = %@ AND resolution.idResolution = %@ AND time > %@", uuid, resolutionID, dateFrom as CVarArg)
realm.objects(DeviceDataRealm.self).filter(predicate)
```

It works only without the `Date` variable:

```
realm.objects(DeviceDataRealm.self).filter("device.uuid == '\(uuid)' AND resolution.idResolution == \(resolutionID))
```

Any idea??

Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually looking for past or future dates? I think it's just your comparison operator that's flipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using predicates, you shouldn't embed the variable values inside the predicates, since that can often lead to problems, but should use the `%@` inside the predicate and write the variable names after the predicate.

However,the issue was with mixing up the comparison operators. I think you misunderstood how variables should be embedded to predicates. Looking at the extract of your Realm model class definition, there's no property named `time`, only `dateFrom`. Class properties should either be inside the predicate as normal Strings or referred to using the `%K` syntax, while the variable names you want to filter for should be referenced to using the `%@` syntax.

Below code was tested in a Realm playground and outputs the expected result.

```
class DeviceDataRealm: Object {
    var uuid: String = ""
    var resolutionID: Int = 0
    var dateFrom: Date = Date()
}

let deviceData = [DeviceDataRealm(value: ["dateFrom":Date.distantPast,"resolutionID":1]),DeviceDataRealm(value: ["dateFrom":Date.distantFuture,"resolutionID":2])]
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(deviceData)
}

let searchUuid = "",searchResolutionID = 2, searchDateFrom = Date()
print(realm.objects(DeviceDataRealm.self).filter("uuid = %@ AND resolutionID = %@ AND dateFrom > %@", searchUuid, searchResolutionID, searchDateFrom))
```

Output:

> Results <0x7fcc2c642280> (
>       [0] DeviceDataRealm {
>           uuid = ;
>           resolutionID = 2;
>           dateFrom = 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000;
>       }
>   )